# Powershell remote install/app run

Tags: powershell

I am going to try and install software remotely onto a server and first i am trying to play around with the invoke-command cmdlet in powerhsell.  Below is what I have so far

```
cls
Exit-PSSession 
New-PSSession -ComputerName vm912test
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName vm912test -Credential sceris\pmanca 
Invoke-Command -Computername vm912test -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "calc.exe" -wait}
```

Get-PSSession

However when i run this i see no running tasks in task manager.  Does anyone know what i am missing?  Once i can get this to work i will expand onto trying to remotely install some software first.  I have no issues on communicating with the server and i have remote access/admin access on the box.

I updated with some more code but still receiving the same result that nothing is happening.

Comment: does it throw any errors? im pretty sure you have to get WinRM running on that box first or else it cant connect. I've found this to be a particularly complicated process and havent really gotten it working smoothly myself.

Comment: It throws no errors.  it just runs(because of the -wait) and i never see in task manager calc.exe.  By winrm do you mean windows remote management service? that is running currently

Comment: it also can run and say complete if i just run that line above and not Enable-PSRemoting beforehand.